# What is the main task of the LLVM Backend

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to explain and summarize for myself in a brief, not too oversimplifying form, what exactly happens in the LLVM Backend - mostly to check if I got the concept correct.

I feel that the main task is to select appropriate "real" machine instructions and replace generic LLVM IR instructions.
To be able to do so, the backend implementation contains all relevant information about registers and instructions.
The passes are the working horse as in they do the choosing. As the LLVM Backend docu states, the goal is to create code for a specific target (or other language, but thats not relevant here I guess)

So how far off am I? As this is not a pure coding problem, I didn't do much despite googling and reading docs and listening to talks but never really got (or maybe missed?) the answer.

Comment: Is your question actually about LLVM specifically or are you wondering how a generic compiler backend works?

Comment: It is about the LLVM backend specifically (Though I wouldn't mind learning the overall thinking of it)